# confusion with varargs and string arrays

Tags: java

```
 class CmndLineArguments {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int length = args.length;
    if (length <= 0) {
    System.out.println("You need to enter some arguments.");
    }
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.println(args[i]);
   }
   }
   }
```

---

```
command : java CmndLineArguments Mahendra zero one two three
output:
Mahendra
zero
one
two
three
```

how does this code work? we are using a String[] args , so are we not supposed to pass arguments like new String[]{.....}..?

and then what is the difference/advantage  between this form and String...s form...because
the varargs is used to to pass zero or more arguments 
in the String[] args also we can run it without zero user input( or does java supple some arguments by default?)

Answer (score 1):

The main method is special. It gets called by the JRE not by the command line. The JRE collates the arguments and gives them to the main method as an array. This preceded var args and is not related to them.

Comment: ohkay so automatic autoboxing to string array takes place?

Comment: yes pretty much, if you look at older languages such as c or pascal you will see they behave the same way. It was just the way language designers chose to send program arguments to the program. Command line interpreters usually wouldn't understand `MyProgram(new String[]{...})`

Comment: hmm...one last thing..how can it run with zero params??
because String[] args should have atleast one argument ,shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> how does this code work? we are using a String[] args , so are we not
>   supposed to pass arguments like new String[]{.....}..?

JVM creates the array of all the inputs and will pass to your main method. This is applicable only for the main method as it is starting point of an application and this method is called by JVM

> and then what is the difference/advantage between this form and
>   String...s form...because the varargs is used to to pass zero or more
>   arguments in the String[] args also we can run it without zero user
>   input( or does java supple some arguments by default?

varargs allow you to take multiple number of params for any method. If you don't use varargs then it is your code job to create an array of params and pass it to the method that accepts an array of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The main method is special, the String[] notation is the classic one, but I have seen the String... notation quite often nowadays. In fact, I think it is more concise with varargs because, you know, you don't have a fixed number or arguments in the command line.

I don't know if JVM converts the arguments to string array or string varargs, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

> so are we not supposed to pass arguments like new String[]{.....}..?

NO, you cannot. After declare that array, from where do you pass that to main method ?. NO.

> **public static void main(String[] args)**

That is the starting point of your program and those args pick by `jvm` from command line.

[From official docs of main](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN)

> Each string in the array is called a command-line argument. Command-line arguments let users affect the operation of the application without recompiling it. For example, a sorting program might allow the user to specify that the data be sorted in descending order with this command-line argument:

And the difference between  `args` and `... args`

> > public static void someMethod(String[] args)**

When you are passing args to here, caller should declare a array and pass the array object here.

> > public static void someMethod(String... args)

Here you don't know the number of passing passing parameters ,and allowing method caller to pass multiple `String` objects.

Here is the Official docs on [Varargas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

> > The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments. Varargs can be used only in the final argument position.

Comment: umm .. i knew all this , it was this specific question that it violated the rule ..the program ran without  passing new String[]{....} to String [] args...but now that i know that for the main method it converts it into array , so..

Comment: @user2837260 Well, you  cannot do that.